# Blank space between Head and Menu

Tags: html, css

I have this problem, rigth now i know basics about html and css and i take the challenge to orginize the look of this web page, but i did something and know it have a space between the address bar and the menu, i has tried many things but still i dont get the problem.

Thanks a lot to anybody that help me

```
CSS Index
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main{
    position: relative;
    margin: 70px auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 480;
}

.contenedor-destacados{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(232, 236, 237, 0.29);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.title-destacados{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
    letter-spacing: 1.3px;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
}
```

CSS Menu

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

 }

 body{
     font-family: 'Roboto';
     /*background-image: url('../img/portada_index_large.jpg');*/
 }

 .material-icons .icon-menu{
     color: black;

 }

 header{
     width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: block;
     height: 15px;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: rgb(3, 3, 3);
     z-index: 1000;
} 

/*.contenedor-noticia{
     position: static;
     margin-top: 0;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%; 
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     background: url(../img/portada_index1.png) no-repeat center bottom;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: right;
     background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)
 }*/

 .navegacion-drawer{
     display: none;
 }

 .btn-menu{
     display: none;
 }

 .cont-logo-head{
     float: left;
     vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .logo-head{
      margin: 4px 10px;
      float: left;
  }

  .title-menu-bar{
      color: #d1d1d1;
      float: left;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-top: 7px;
      letter-spacing: 2px; 
   }

   .navegacion{
       width: 685px;
       top: 2px;
       display: block;
       position: relative;
       float: right;
       height: 56px;
       padding: 0;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       z-index: 500;
       margin-right: 3px;
    }

    .menu-general{
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 640;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: rgb(3, 3, 3);
    }

    .menu{
        float: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .menu:before{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 3px;
        background: #CBCBCB;
        transition: all .5s;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX05p.png)

Comment: You should post your html code as well

Comment: You should run your site through a validator; it contains structural errors such as a div in the middle of the head.

Comment: I don't know which part u need, and the code is too long :D

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will, do you have any recomendation to validate it?

Comment: You can use the official one, https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks!! i checked it, and have a lot of mistakes, i will have to fix it. I invite you to visit it www.globaltcompany.com, thanks to you and the other user i get to fix it, now i have problems with the responsive part lmao

Comment: Let me know any recomendation that you could have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because in your `.main` you have

`margin: 70px auto`

I don't know your page so this may not be it, but try changing to `margin: 0 auto`

update: Instead, remove `top:40px` from `.contenedor-destacados`

Comment: Good find! Especially without knowing which site it is. The screenshot will tell you its URL though.

Comment: Thank you!! It works, now i ask you why when i make changes on the code, y have to erase the cache to see the changes, for example, everytime i have to use the Ccleaner and open the web page to see the changes.

Comment: Thank you!! i get to fix the look thanks to you too.
I invite you to visit it www.globaltcompany.com, thanks to you and the other user i get to fix it, now i have problems with the responsive part lmao

Comment: Let me know any recomendation to improve the codding or the design :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `top:0;`

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(3, 3, 3);
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
}
```